# how to get different UI elements by the choicefield value?

Tags: django, filter, choicefield

Here's my code, something is wrong in the `test.html` `if` statement. Could you help me to modified the `if` condition in `test.html` that I can get different UI element by the choice-field value?

forms.py

```
class testForm(forms.Form):
    runtype = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(0, 0), (1, 1)])
    byname = forms.CharField()
    byindex = forms.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def osys(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = testForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            runtype = form.cleaned_data['runtype']
            if runtype == 0:
                byname = form.cleaned_data['byname']
            if runtype == 1:
                byindex = form.cleaned_data['byindex']
            print byname, byindex, runtype, filename
            return HttpResponse('OK')
    else:
        form =  testForm()
    return render_to_response('test.html', locals())
```

test.html

```
<form method="post" >
    {{form.runtype}}
    {% if form.runtype ==0 %}
        {{form.byname}}
    {% if form.runtype ==1 %}
        {{form.byindex}}
    <input type="submit" value="Start Run" name="btnRun"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to close your `if` statements in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Django templates are rendered server side to plain HTML which is sent to the client which has no knowledge of the template code.

If you need to do things dynamically client side, you'll need to use JavaScript.